# How to reduce ram usage in development

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently I'm working on a fullstack website using ~80 npm packages. But the ram usage is too high(sometimes it reach 2.6gb) and my pc become sooo slow. How can i reduce the ram usage? should I install the dependency globally?

[image]

Comment: Do you really need 80 npm packages? That aside, 2.6GB is nothing. I'd consider 16GB to be the minimum for regular development and 32GB to be comfortable. If you also work with graphics (such as in game development), even that may not be enough.

Comment: The memory usage in your screenshot is on the low side with node eating most of it. So, again, do you really need 80 npm packages?

Comment: That's a *very* broad question and isn't really a good fit for SO. Really you need to dig into the application with a profiler of some sort and find the root cause. It could easily be something like a large dataset being returned from a database query, but this question doesn't provide that sort of detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell node to use less RAM (or more RAM) for its heap by running it with this [option](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_max_old_space_size_size_in_megabytes). The number is the requested heap size in MiB.

```
node --max-old-space-size=750 whatever.js
```

1.5GiB is the default size.

If your program is using lots of RAM you may have a [memory leak.](https://nodesource.com/blog/memory-leaks-demystified) That is, you may, by mistake, be keeping references to objects or arrays you no longer need. This could happen in an express application, for example, if a route handler did something (wrong) like this to keep a list of incoming requests.

```
saved_req.push(req)
```

It seems unlikely that just your package code could blow out your RAM. Many node apps use dozens of packages, because top-level ones pull in many dependencies.

All that being said, if your machine is [thrashing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) with one node app, one browser, and one IDE, you really need more physical RAM.